# Layout file not being loaded

Tags: layout, configuration, xml

I'm brand new to Magento and am having trouble getting my config.xml file to load my layout file for the url: "localhost/index.php/moduleone/index/index".  Can somebody help me figure out what I'm missing?

magento/app/code/local/Test/ModuleOne/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_ModuleOne>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_ModuleOne>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            ...
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <moduleone>
                    <file>moduleone.xml</file> <!-- Our layout file name-->
                </moduleone>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        ...
    </global>
</config>
```

magento/app/design/frontend/default/layout/moduleone.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <moduleone_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="moduleone/moduleone" name="moduleone" template="moduleone/moduleone.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </moduleone_index_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? `/app/design/frontend/default/layout/moduleone.xml:`, is it missing a `base` folder? or am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry Tim, the base folder is actually named "magento"... I'll edit the question to clarity.

Comment: There is still the package missing, i.e. `/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/moduleone.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,your template file location is working.

It should be

```
app\design\frontend\YOURPackage\YOURTemplate\layout
```

or  `app\design\frontend\base\default\layout`

As per magento Design fallback logic

Comment: Thanks, Amit.  Looks like the tutorial I was following was using version of Magento that used the path app/design/frontend/default/default for templates and layouts.  Towards the end, the author mentions to use the path you mentioned in your answer.  I wish he had made that point more obvious!

Comment: In case it'll help anybody else, I posted a full example of a solution that renders a template and block: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340402/magento-config-file-not-loading-layout/30496471#30496471

Answer (score 4):

I always avoid Camel casing in Package and Module Name.

```
    <frontend>
      ----
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <moduleone module="Test_ModuleOne">
                <file>moduleone.xml</file>
            </moduleone>
          </updates>
         </layout>
    </frontend>
```

And Place you moduleone.xml at app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\moduleone.xml

I hope this will help you out.
Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks, Robin.  I'll have to try your solution sometime.  I went with Amit's solution below because that seemed to be along the lines of this tutorial that I've been following.